# Pandas group check if timestamp for certain value is earlier than timestamp for other certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at a dataframe full of orders, which have timestamps, order is and an operation status for inserting/updating/canceling the order. The dataframe looks as follows:

| Index | TIMESTAMP | ORDER_ID | OPERATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-09-01 13:49:00.000 | 123 | INSERT |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 13:49:25.000 | 123 | UPDATE |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 13:49:37.000 | 123 | CANCEL |
| 3 | 2022-09-01 13:49:48.000 | 456 | CANCEL |
| 4 | 2022-09-01 13:49:49.000 | 456 | UPDATE |
| 5 | 2022-09-01 13:49:50.000 | 456 | INSERT |

As part of my data analysis, I would like to clean up the data to filter out "flawed" orders.
I was able to filter out operations that are missing an insert/update/cancel using `df.groupby('ORDER_ID').filter(lambda x: (x.OPERATION == "CANCEL").any())` (repeating the code with the different operations, not efficient).

Next, I would like to filter out those orders in which the "ordering" (i.e., time when they occur) of the operations is wrong, e.g., when a CANCEL (or UPDATE) occurs before an INSERT.

How could I filter out those cases? It should check the TIMESTAMP of an CANCEL operation for that order id group, and check if that timestamp is earlier than the TIMESTAMP of an INSERT operation. Ideally, the solution should be handle cases when there are multiple of the same OPERATION for the  same order ID, e.g., in some cases the OPERATIONS are occuring more than once (at different timestamps).

My idea so far:
`df.groupby(["ORDER_ID", "OPERATION"])['TIMESTAMP'].first()` gives me a table that shows the first occurences of each different OPERATION for the ORDER_IDs. Now I would just need some way to compare those returned values inside.

Comment: Somehow the table formatting got lost, it looked fine in the preview..

Comment: You needed a blank line before the table begins

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for fixing it! A bit confusing that it got displayed properly in the preview

Comment: Yeah, I had that too. Looks like a bug in the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes, replace not matched datimes to missing values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and get minimal datetime per groups, last compare both columns:

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])

df1 = (df.assign(s1 = df['TIMESTAMP'].where(df['OPERATION'].eq('INSERT')),
                 s2 = df['TIMESTAMP'].where(df['OPERATION'].isin(['UPDATE','CANCEL'])))
          .groupby('ORDER_ID')[['s1','s2']]
          .transform('min'))


df = df[df1.s1.lt(df1.s2)]
print (df)
            TIMESTAMP  ORDER_ID OPERATION
0 2022-09-01 13:49:00       123    INSERT
1 2022-09-01 13:49:25       123    UPDATE
2 2022-09-01 13:49:37       123    CANCEL
```

Comment: Gonna give it a try, looks much neater than my idea of using .first() repeatedly (to first get  the first occurence for each OPERATION within order ID groups, and then the first occurence of those operations) and then checking if that first is an INSERT.

Code is currently running, might take a while since the dataframe contains about 6M lines

Comment: Question - for which column is the transform('min') finding the minimum? Don't we have to tell it to minimize by TIMESTAMP somewhere?

Comment: @Olorun - by `[['s1','s2']]`, added to solution.